# Storing relationships in Realm (Java)

Tags: android-sqlite, realm, realm-list, realm-java

I'm starting to use Realm to store objects in my Android app. Here's an example of what I'm looking to store:

```
public class Item implements RealmModel {
    String id;
    ...
}
```

I have multiple lists that display items. The number of lists can keep expanding (the user can create as many lists as possible.

Let's say the user create's a list called "Best". When I'm viewing the "Best" list I call `getItems("Best")` which gets a `List<Items>` from the API. I now have to figure out how to store this list. In SQLite world I would have create a new table "custom_list_best", for example, which is just a single list of all the Item.id's that are part of the list. I would also have an "items" table that has all the distinct Items. To get items in the best list I would simply do a join query on both the best and items tables.

In the Realm world I'm trying to figure out how Realm works and what's the best way to build my models.

I initially thought I could create an object called `CustomList`:

```
public class CustomList implements RealmModel {
    String listId;
    RealmList<Item> items;
}
```

I would then store a `RealmList<CustomList>`. But the only issue is I also want to be able to query against all Items. So I need to also store a `RealmList<Item>` in Realm. How does Realm work in this case? If I store a separate `RealmList<Item>` and then store each `RealmList<CustomList>` will it not duplicate data?

Instead will I have to manually handle this by doing this instead:

```
public class CustomList implements RealmModel {
    String listId;
    List<String> itemIds;
}
```

And then query for `Item.class` objects that have itemId in itemIds from above object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In SQLite world I would have create a new table "custom_list_best",

No, you would have a table called `custom_lists` with an auto-increment ID and an identifier, and a join table called `join_custom_lists_items` that would contain the ID of `custom_lists` and the ID of any `item` that belongs to that given custom list.

> In the Realm world I'm trying to figure out how Realm works and what's the best way to build my models.

If the `ID` of the item is concrete and you need to be able to store the same `Item` in multiple lists, then in order to access the lists in both directions, you'll need a `RealmList<? extends RealmModel>` in both cases.

```
@RealmClass
public class Item implements RealmModel {
    @PrimaryKey
    private String id;

    private RealmList<CustomList> customLists;

    // getter setter
}
```

And

```
@RealmClass
public class CustomList implements RealmModel {
    @PrimaryKey
    private String title; // assuming you cannot name two lists the same? otherwise do `@Index`

    private RealmList<Item> items;

    // getter setter
}
```

This way you can do

```
realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
  public void execute(Realm realm) {
    Item item = realm.where(Item.class).equalTo(ItemFields.ID, itemId).findFirst(); // assuming exists
    CustomList customList = realm.where(CustomList.class).equalTo(CustomListFields.TITLE, "Best").findFirst();
    if(customList == null) {
         customList = realm.createObject(CustomList.class, "Best");
    }
    customList.getItems().add(item);
    item.getCustomLists().add(customList);
  }
}
```

And then you can query

```
RealmResults<Item> bestItems = realm.where(Item.class)
                                    .equalTo(ItemFields.CustomLists.TITLE, "Best")
                                            //same as "customLists.title"
                                    .findAll();
```

All this `Fields` stuff I'm using is from https://github.com/cmelchior/realmfieldnameshelper